# R: plot circular histograms/rose diagrams on map

Tags: r, plot, rose-plot

I am trying to plot rose diagrams/ circular histograms on specific coordinates on a map analogous to drawing pie charts on a map as in the package `mapplots`.

Below is an example generated with `mapplots` (see below for code), I'd like to replace the pie charts with rose diagrams

[image: example plot]

The package `circular` lets me plot the rose diagrams, but I am unable to integrate it with the `mapplots` package. Any suggestions for alternative packages or code to achieve this?

In response to the question for the code to make the map. It's all based on the `mapplots` package. I downloaded a shapefile for the map (I think from http://www.freegisdata.org/)

```
library(mapplots)
library(shapefiles)

xlim = c(-180, 180)
ylim = c(-90, 90)

#load shapefile
wmap = read.shapefile ("xxx")

# define x,y,z for pies
x <- c(-100, 100)
y <- c(50, -50)
z1 <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)
z2 <- c(0.5, 0.2, 0.3)
z <- rbind(z1,z2)
# define radii of the pies
r <- c(5, 10)

# it's easier to have all data in a single df

plot(NA, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, cex = 0.75, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
draw.shape(wmap, col = "grey", border = "NA")
draw.pie(x,y,z,radius = r, col=c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
legend.pie (x = -160, y = -70, labels = c("0", "1", "2"), radius = 5,
bty = "n", cex = 0.5, label.dist=1.5, col = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
```

the legend for the pie size can then be added using legend.bubble

Comment: Cool map! Any chance you could post the code for it as an example?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744375/how-to-plot-contours-on-a-map-with-ggplot2-when-data-is-on-an-irregular-grid), you can use the map as background an plot your rose diagrams with`Plotrix` or `ggplot2`. In either case you would want to overlay multiple of these diagrams on top of your map which is easy to do in ggplot, just have a look at the example.

Comment: Apologies, I don't think my question was very clear. It's not about how to plot rose diagrams, but how to get them on a map. Hopefully the example above clarifies this.

Comment: hey lukas you could use multiple plots made in plotrix and use a `grid()` to plot them on top of your map image. you want me to clarify it for you?

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi Nellen. I can plot the map and the rose diagrams (using 'coord.polar') individually. However, from your example it isn't clear to me how I make sure that the rose diagrams are plotted at the right coordinates. I'd be grateful if you could clarify your suggestion to use 'grid()'.

Comment: yes I can do that but maybe not today, could you wait until the weekend? Then I could make you an great example.

Comment: Thanks again @Mehdi Nellen. I kept on looking for a solution and think I found one myself. See below

Answer (score 2):

I discovered subplot() in the package `Hmisc`, which seems to do exactly what I wanted. Below is my solution (without the map in the background, which can be plotted using `mapplots`). I am open to suggestions on how to improve this though...

```
library(Hmisc)
library (circular)

dat <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:360,10,rep=TRUE)))
lat <- c(50, -40)
lon <- c(-100, 20)

# convert to class circular
cir.dat <- as.circular (dat, type ='angles', units = 'degrees', template = 'geographic', modulo = 'asis', zero = 'pi/2', rotation = 'clock')

# function for subplot, plots relative frequencies, see rose.diag for how to adjust the plot
sub.rose <- function(x){
                nu <- sum(!is.na(x))
                de <- max(hist(x, breaks = (seq(0, 360, 30)), plot = FALSE)$counts)
                prop <- nu/de
                rose.diag(x, bins = 12, ticks = FALSE, axes = FALSE,
                radii.scale = 'linear',
                border = NA, 
                prop = prop,
                col = 'black'
                )
                }

plot(NA, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
for(i in 1:length(lat)){
    subplot(sub.rose(cir.dat[,i]), x = lon[i], y = lat[i], size = c(1, 1))
    }
```